# Error while creating extension Swift 4 : Use of undeclared type 'UIFont'

Tags: ios, swift3

I am creating Extension of `UIFont`, it gives an error. I am attaching a screenshot of it. This error goes away when import `UIFont`.

```
import Foundation

extension UIFont {    
    class func appRegularFont(with size:CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: size)!
    }

    class func appMediumFont(with size:CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: size)!
    }

    class func appBoldFont(with size:CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: size)!
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: try to import UIKit

Comment: Yes, I already mentioned in the question that it goes away when import UIKit, but it works with that in my other project. That is the reason I wanted to know the issue. Any other reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to your extension file and import this

**import UIKit**

Comment: Yes, I already mentioned in the question that it goes away when import UIKit, but it works with that in my other project. That is the reason I wanted to know the issue. Any other reason.

Comment: @SantoshSingh This **is** the reason. Your *other project* certainly imports `UIKit` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your other project likely imports UIKit implicitly somewhere. For example, if you have a bridging header to include ObjC, and that bridging header imports UIKit, then UIKit will implicitly be available everywhere in Swift. Somewhere you need to import UIKit.